# Drush on windows - back up goes missing

Tags: drush, backups

I am new to drupal and drush, so please do not close this if it's naive.

My setup:

- Windows 7
- Xampp 1.8.3 (PHP 5.5.6/Apache 2.4.7/PHP 5.5.6)
- Drupal 7.26
- Drush 6.3-dev

Intention:

Back up my site and restore on a separate machine using `drush
    archive-dump` and `drush archive-restore`

Action: I went into the folder where I have installed drupal and issued the command `drush archive-dump`

Result:

```
Archive saved to                                                            [ok]

C:\Users\srihari.sahu/drush-backups/archive-dump/20140206101025/drup
al.20140206_101027.tar.gz
C:\Users\srihari.sahu/drush-backups/archive-dump/20140206101025/drup
al.20140206_101027.tar.gz
```

When I go in the folder `C:\Users\srihari.sahu\drush-backups\archive-dump\20140206101025\` I don't see anything. The folder is blank.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue for drush in Windows, along with several others regarding sql operations and rsync. The best solution I know so far is described in:

https://drupal.org/node/1393672